# Disable Top Navigation Across A Site and Its Subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hello I have create a new site with individual team sites (sub sites). Each site displays links to other team sites in the top navigation. I do not even though they shouldn't have permissions to the other subsites, I do not want them to have the link.

How can I disable this?

Here is an example of the url structure. All of the sites from Projects (Team(n)) are getting display across the whole Projects site.

https://baseurl.sharepoint.com/site/Projects/Team1
https://baseurl.sharepoint.com/site/Projects/Team2

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can not disable it. Either you can remove it or you can set audience to it.  Follow the below steps to remove or set the audience.

1. Login with site admin root site
2. On top navigation click on Edit button. refer below screen shot.

[image: Top Navigation]

3. You set the audience using below screen

[image: Remove or Set Audience]

4. For removing link  click on ellipsis and remove it. refer the below screen.
   [image]
5. Reference

- [Target content to a specific audience on a SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-content-to-a-specific-audience-on-a-sharepoint-site-68113d1b-be99-4d4c-a61c-73b087f48a81)
- [Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: I am using the classic experience so I do not have this view/option